# Why does $event.preventDefault() in AngularJS not prevent context menu from appearing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

Like the title says, I'm not sure why `$event.preventDefault()` is not preventing the context menu from appearing on right click.

I've written [this simple example](http://plnkr.co/edit/kN2L7lLpUranXw8PGfx4) in plunker to demonstrate the problem.

Html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="me" ng-mousedown="stopContext($event)">CLICK ME {{num}}</div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
  $scope.stopContext = function(ev) {
    $scope.num += 1;
    ev.preventDefault();
  };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: context menu show not on mousedown

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to prevent the context-menu you need to capture (and prevent) the **[`contextmenu`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/#t03)** event.

Unfortunately, Angular does not have a directive for this event, so you'll have to create one yourself.

"Copying" from the source code of Angular (version 1.2.16):

```
app.directive('myContextmenu', function ($parse) {
  return {
    compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
      var fn = $parse(tAttrs.myContextmenu);

      return function (scope, elem) {
        elem.on('contextmenu', onContextmenu);

        function onContextmenu(evt) {
          scope.$apply(function () {
            fn(scope, {$event: evt});
          });
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
<div id="me" my-contextmenu="stopContext($event)">CLICK ME {{num}}</div>
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZshrSRcTusM9RGcyEfPx?p=preview)**.
<sub>Tested on latest version of Chrome, Firefox and Safari and found working.</sub>