# Understanding specific $scope.$apply(fn) implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

What does the following function wrapped by scope.$apply do? I can't seem to find the answer to this, but I see examples where it is used in directives.

```
            scope.$apply(function() {
                fn(scope, {
                    $event: evt
                })
            });
```

The closest explanation I could find implies that this might be used when the event that you want to respond to is not handled by Angular directives. Here is the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23590045/1990536) I am referring to.

If someone could provide the intended use of this pattern and what it means, it would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I should have seen this earlier. Must need more sleep. 
Since my example is not a complete working one. It makes a lot more sense after looking at the referenced explanation carefully. 
The `fn(scope, {$event: evt})` call is invoking the parsed reference to a custom function via the directive parsed in the following line:

```
var fn = $parse(tAttrs.myContextmenu);
```

So the target function implementation is capturing a specific event via the directive and then suppressing it.

So I guess this is useful when you do not want to clutter directives with controller specific functions and maybe fire a different event in response to another event then let a controller handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scope.$apply` is used to manually trigger Angular's digest cycle for any async events that happen outside of Angular's execution context.

One such async event is `element.on("click", function(e){...})` (or any other event related captured with `.on`), but could also be other async function outside of Angular context.

The second part is an invocation of the "$parsed" expression. It accepts a scope as a parameter and a map of "local" variables, such as `{$event: evt}`. The intent is every similar to what `scope: "&"` is doing - but without creating an isolate scope. For example, if the expression is:

```
<my-directive p="doSomething(foo)">
```

then, if `doSomething(foo)` is $parsed, the caller can supply the value of `foo`:

```
var parsedFn = $parse(attrs.p);
parsedFn(scope, {foo: 5})'
```

This will cause the invocation of `doSomething(5)`

Comment: Thanks! I missed the line showing `$parse` earlier so when I noticed it prior to your post, everything clicked. I like that you mentioned there being no need for the creation of isolate scope. I think the `element.on` events are what tripped me up. I was assuming that Angular was wrapping them, but it is only the custom `ng-*` events that get wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer to this since it makes sense to me (see my edit).

The `fn(scope, {$event: evt})` call is invoking the parsed reference to a custom function via the directive parsed in the following line:

```
var fn = $parse(tAttrs.myContextmenu);
```

So the target function implementation is capturing a specific event via the directive and then suppressing it.

So I guess this is useful when you do not want to clutter directives with controller specific functions and maybe fire a different event in response to another event then let a controller handle it.